# Is the EMH AI somehow technologically inferior to Soong androids?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-picard

I started watching *Star Trek: Picard* last night and even though it's set after *Voyager*, Data and his AI are treated as unique. I've never actually watched *The Next Generation*, but was a huge fan of *Voyager*. Several episodes were dedicated to The Doctor's humanity and growth -- it certainly seemed like the Emergency Medical Hologram's AI was at least on par with Data's.

So why is Data treated like a unique being? He is not the only example of an AI who grew and developed. It would be crazy to believe The Doctor wouldn't become a well-known case study upon Voyager's return, especially to characters in *Picard* whose academic focus is on AI development.

The obvious out-of-universe answer is that Picard the character has a much stronger connection to Data, and mixing the EMH into the plot would muddy the waters. That said, is there an in-universe explanation for why no one who studies AI seems even remotely aware of Voyager's EMH?

Comment: Hmm, it's almost like the writers of Picard were not actually very well acquainted with Star Trek...

Comment: @Harabeck I really think that criticism is unfounded. All the recent Star Treks are full of references to all the previous shows. When something’s been produced for over 50 years, there will always be continuity holes to pick. *TNG* contradicted both the Original Series and itself several times. Lieutenant Dax doesn’t sit particularly well with the portrayal of the Trill in that one *TNG* episode, but *Deep Space Nine* is still worth a watch. There’s plenty to criticise in every Star Trek series, but “ignoring previous Star Trek” is way, way down the list.

Comment: @Harabeck: Data was depicted as unique and impossible to reproduce in TNG, and the medical hologram dates back to Voyager. Therefore it doesn't really make sense to blame this on the writers of Picard.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55472/2490

Comment: It's worth noting that while Voyager's EMH did seem to develop sentience, this is not true of the EMH's on other ships.  The Voyager example was an exception due to the fact that he had to be active pretty much full time since there was no flesh-and-blood medic on the ship.  We've occasionally seen other versions of the EMH on other ships (e.g. the one in *First Contact*) and they seem far less - "developed" as it were.  So the Voyager EMH is actually fairly uncommon - less common than Soong androids really, since there's only 1 that we know of.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Have you seen Picard? Picard was never particularly close to Data, Geordi was. The Romulan Star Empire is comparable in size the Klingon Empire and the Cardassion Union. The idea that they wouldn't be able to evacuate Romulus without Federation help is nonsense. Picard had experienced having a family (though probably in a simulation). Seven was a brilliant scientist and had more than one straight relationship in Voyager; nothing about her character in Picard makes sense. And so on. They didn't just miss some details. Nearly every aspect of the story is flawed.

Comment: @Harabeck: Picard was never particularly close to Data? Sure. He just defended his legal right to self-determination, gave him personal tutoring in Shakespeare on the holodeck, and had his life saved by him. Just a standard colleague relationship, that one. As for Seven having had "more than one straight relationship", you might want to broaden the range of real-life humans you talk to about sexuality if you want to clear up what I assume is your confusion about her holding hands with a woman.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Picard would have defended any member of his crew, and Data saved more than just Picard with his sacrifice. Go find any scene where Data talks about his friends, and it's Geordi that comes up, not Picard. He valued and respected Data, but the idea that he would sit around pining for him for decades is just weird. And if you think them holding hands isn't bad screen writer for "they're together", then you haven't watched much bad TV (which, to be fair, is a good life goal). Also, it's pretty heavily implied that Seven had a relationship with Bjayzl as well.

Comment: “The Romulan Star Empire is comparable in size the Klingon Empire and the Cardassion Union. The idea that they wouldn't be able to evacuate Romulus without Federation help is nonsense.” I'm not sure we can dismiss the idea that it might be difficult for even a galactic power to evacuate billions of people, but the idea itself is [from the 2009 Star Trek movie](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan_sun#The_Romulan_supernova). As I said, there's plenty to criticise, but ignoring previous Star Trek, not so much.

Comment: @Harabeck: sure, Geordi's Data's best friend. I don't see how that rules out Picard having deep feelings for Data. I think it's fairly clear in The Next Generation that Picard feels invested in Data's pursuit of humanity, and clear from Nemesis that he's deeply affected by Data sacrificing himself for Picard, very much against Picard's wishes.

Comment: @Harabeck: On Seven and Raffi, yup, I get the implication that they're together (or at least flirting), and the implication of Seven having had a relationship with Bjayzl. I don't think that's a contradiction of Seven's earlier romantic relationships with men; I think that you thinking it is demonstrates a lack of awareness on your part about how human sexuality actually works.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You're missing the point. It's got nothing to do with sexuality per se. It could have been that she really loves pancakes. Like, just at some random point she really started liking pancakes and they took the time to point it out. That's perfectly plausible, but they've provided no background or development for this change, and it doesn't serve the larger narrative. They've just made the character different. And it's not the only way, either. They've also turned a brilliant calculating scientist into a drunk emotional vigilante. Why? They don't respect the original character.

Comment: @Harabeck: so you're annoyed because Seven changed. Fair enough. I would point out that in *Voyager*, it wasn't like Seven was a regular human adult. She was recovering from being a Borg drone, having been assimilated during childhood. Most of what I remember of her during Voyager was her fairly slowly discovering her humanity, much like Data in TNG. I'm not sure that would make sense decades later. I can understand if you really like that Seven, and really don't like future Seven, but I don't think every aspect of every character has to have background, or a specific role in the narrative.

Comment: As far as the drunk emotional vigilante bit goes, you did notice Icheb being brutally murdered for his Borg implants, right. And Seven, understandably, taking that pretty hard? If that's not background for the vigilantism and the drinking, I really don't know what is.

Comment: After having finished the first season, I see @Harabecks'spoint -- not because of "we never saw when seven came out" but because.... There never seemed to be any chemistry in either of the romantic pairings we saw in the final five seconds. They just feel like they were added as a whim, which doesn't feel very star trekky, as we every rarely see regular crew members couple up.

Comment: @Sidney: yeah, maybe. Raffi and Seven are both kind of a mess, and a bit self-destructive; personally I could totally see them getting together for a short time before it all blew up. I know that historically, Star Trek hasn't really handled relationships in that way, but as I said back at the start of this, it's been on for over 50 years. You can't literally keep making the same show for that long. People have been furious at every new Star Trek show for doing something allegedly un-Star-Trekky. And that's fine, it's just not very interesting to read "that's not Star Trek" yet again.

Comment: People still don't realize that "New Trek" doesn't care one bit about continuity. How is that possible?

Comment: @HamSandwich, oh, and TOS was the very model of continuity? Please.

Comment: TOS is Star Trek. Picard is nonsense.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- The holodeck [accidentally created a self-aware Moriarty](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Elementary,_Dear_Data_(episode)) when Geordi asked it to create an opponent that could beat Data.
- Data himself discovered [a group of maintenance robots that had accidentally become self-aware](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Quality_of_Life_(episode)) on Tyrus VIIa .
- Even the Enterprise's main computer [accidentally became self-aware](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emergence_%28episode%29) while Data was still on-board.

So, even ignoring the Emergency Medical Hologram*, accidental artificial intelligence (in the sense of [artificial consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_consciousness)) is apparently a semi-regular occurrence in the *Next Generation* time frame. (It probably would have happened more during the Original Series if it weren't for Kirk running around shouting the [Liar's Paradox](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/I,_Mudd_(episode)#Act_Four) at anything that looked a bit like an android.)

*Intentional* artificial intelligence, however, is apparently more difficult. Data, [and his kin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Android#Soong-type_androids), were the only known example of sentient androids being intentionally and successfully designed and created. No-one else — [including Data](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Offspring_(episode)) — could figure out how reproduce that achievement.

As per *Star Trek: Picard*, the Daystrom Institute eventually successfully created [synths](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/F8). This work may have been informed by studies of Voyager's EHM and similar emergent AIs, although the synths didn't quite seem to have the same degree of sentience as Data or the Doctor. Perhaps the emergent AIs were studied, but it wasn't possible to understand or reproduce what led to their emergence**.

**STAR TREK: PICARD *SPOILERS AHEAD:***

> Bruce Maddox later created [Dahj](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dahj_Asha) and [Soji](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Soji_Asha), from a single positronic neuron of Data's; this is presumably unrelated to emergent AIs like the EMH. They did seem to have the level of sentience one would expect from Soong-type androids. However, they were kept secret, as all development of artificial intelligence was outlawed following the apparent Synth attack on Mars.

<sub>* A difficult, but necessary task at the best of times.</sub>

<sub>** Or those pesky Federation ethics limited the amount of study that could be done. I hold out hope that the Doctor wasn't terminated under the AI laws, and serves as a kind of benevolent tenor King on a planet of sentient holograms somewhere. If you know anyone on the *Picard* season 2 staff, I have a great spec script for them.</sub>

Comment: Marked as the correct answer for mentioning that data was the only intentional AI -- all the others were accidental.

Comment: Agnes Jurati clearly states in Picard S1E1 that, "B-4 wasn't much like Data. No other synth has been." clearly implying that the synths shown on Mars in the show weren't truly sentient.

Comment: It may not be intention--the EMH and Moriarty are not self-contained entities, but need substantial (external) computing power and specialized holographic emitters to exist.  Both characters have to deal with that limitation when they want to exit an environment with holodeck capability.  The exocomps were self-contained, but their intellectual capabilities are highly specialized, and they compare to Data maybe like a lizard compares to a human.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I take the point that Data’s positronic brain is probably hypercrazypants (that’s a technical term) beyond any other AI-producing hardware, in that it fits in a human-sized head, and draws power only from a human-sized body. It’s possible the Daystrom institute could have created an equivalent AI consciousness, just not in a mobile body like Data’s, and chose not to, possibly due to the ethical considerations of trapping such a consciousness in a big-ass computer. But I think the more likely explanation is that they just couldn’t reproduce the accidental AIs.

Comment: I mean, Picard apparently successfully trapped Moriarty in the holodeck, without Moriarty realising he was trapped. It feels like if reproducing AI in a big computer was possible, the Daystrom nerds would have done that in a universe-simulation, then tried to work out how to miniaturise the hardware. But maybe not! Star Trek is incredibly vague on what AI actually is. At times one would almost think that the writers don’t have a deep and detailed technical understanding of how computers work.

Comment: The EMH isn't an accidental AI.  It was designed from the ground up to be a learning program (essentially an AI).  It just wasn't meant to be left on for so long.  The issue with the Doctor's programming isn't that he wasn't meant to learn, it was that his programming wasn't designed to learn that much.  As for sentience, the Doctor seems to be on par with Data, and Voyager had encountered many AI that knew they existed.  Sentience isn't much of a benchmark for digital life, or life in general.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Was all of Data's computational power stored solely in his head? I know the core of it was the positronic brain which definitely was, but Soong wasn't forced to rely on an analogue of human internal layout for functionality, were all of the secondary systems required for his sentience there too?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Data seems able to remain as sentient as usual even when the rest of him is unavailable. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JT52AzJ1wec

Comment: @Nathaniel: are you sure? His sense of deadpan comic timing isn't... [no, wait, it's fully functional](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JT52AzJ1wec&t=0m49s).

Comment: @McFuu: sure. When I say "accidental AI", I mean accidental strong AI, as in [artificial general intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence) and/or [artificial consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_consciousness). As you say, sentience — it's arguable that's not a great benchmark, but it seems to be the benchmark that *Star Trek* uses to distinguish Data from some other artificial life.

Comment: "no-one else could figure out how to do it" Data got pretty close, with Lal.

Comment: @GrahamLee: let's ask Lal how close he got! Oh wait, we can't, _she's dead._

Comment: I have heard (though only rumours) that Robert Picardo is involved in *Picard* S2, though no details on how he's involved or to what degree.

Comment: @RichardWard I'm taking this as gospel and I swear if he's not in at least half of s2 I'm gonna be mad at you.

Comment: @RichardWard I heard a rumour that Dwight Schultz was involved with season 2 to the nth degree, but it turned out to be a misreading of an old IMDB listing.

Comment: Positronic neuron, not positron neutron.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs: thank you!

Comment: It still says neutron instead of neuron. This is important because 'neuron' makes it more plausible. I can't edit it because of the stupid 'at least six more characters' rule.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs: ah! Sorry, I wasn't paying attention. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 16):

**Portability**

Most of the AIs seen in Star Trek are housed in starship Main Computers.

The ship's computer AI is (obviously) housed in the Main Computer.
The Holodeck characters that gained spontaneous emergent intelligence (Moriarity, Fairhaven etc) are all constructed by the ship's Main Computer.
Though Moriarity is eventually transferred to a portable device to keep the simulation running indefinitely. The possibility that the simulation is running a lot slower to allow for lesser hardware is unstated, but explains why the holodeck is usually run via the main computer rather than its own onboard equipment.

The EMH is unusual in that he has his own separate computer hardware, but it's still very much non-portable, integrated into the ship.
The Mobile Emitter is the product of hundreds of years of refinement and doesn't count for our purposes.

Data however is a human-level intelligence AI housed in a human-sized brain (as evidenced by how he can continue to think and talk when his head is severed in at least one or two episodes).
Practically unique in the series for that alone!

**Design-Type**

Apart from the hardware, the EMH and similar AIs are explicitly modelled on existing people, both physically and personality-wise.
The Soong Androids are not. They're an effort to produce AI that grows into its personality from a low baseline (if anything), rather than being a highly sophisticated simulation of a person that has enough intellect to grow from there.

Different approaches, with different limitations and requirements.

Comment: What I like very much about this answer is the aspect of origin. The EMH's program has been condensed from the expertise of the brightest human / biological medical experts of the Federation, supposedly including a lot of their personality in this process.

Comment: The trouble with the second part is that Data contained the stored diaries of ~300 colonists. Granted, it wasn't as large as the EMH's collection of human-produced records; but it also was not restricted to one particular domain of endeavor (that is, medical engineering).

Comment: I'd like to remind you that the sum total written word of humanity at the moment in plain-text format is a matter of terabytes of space. The diaries of a few hundred colonists is trivially small data and I'd be shocked if Data (made with 24th century hardware) couldn't store and retrieve that amount of information with ease. Even factoring in high resolution photos and video footage.

Comment: Another difference is how they learn and develop. Data basically started out with pretty minimal programming (rather like an operating system with no programs installed yet) and learned all of his knowledge by experience in a natural way, similar to how you or I would learn. For example, he completed Starfleet Academy just like anyone else would. The EMH Doctor of Voyager was always programmed as a physician with lots of knowledge built-in. The Doctor did learn from experience on Voyager, but for many, things he needed specific programming help, like getting the ECH upgrades.

Answer (score 10):

An additional thought stemming from lucasbachmann's answer is that while they are of comparable sentience the EMH requires (at least prior to the mobile emitter attained via time travel, and the federation probably has rules about trying to research items attained from the future) an entire ship's computer, while data is mobile in his own right.

Comment: While a fair point, the EMH didn't use up all of the ship's computer power. I don't recall any canon mention of how much it did use, but the rest of the ships functions needed some of it..

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - And when he was in his 'mobile emitter', the EMH (in his entirety) was dramatically smaller than Data's brain.

Comment: @Valorum - But the mobile emitter was from the future. Even if we ignore the fact that it was a handwave to allow his character more freedom to develop, that's an unfair advantage. However, the mobile emitter did nothing for his cognitive abilities or development, so one has to assume it has similar processing power to what the Doctor was able to utilise from Voyager's computer.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins: I recall episodes where the Doctor had to choose which sub-programs to leave behind when, say, going on an away mission. So, he seemed to be larger than what a shuttlecraft or the Delta Flyer computer could handle.

Answer (score 8):

Data is an engineering marvel in terms of his body and his brain being beyond state of the art nanotechnology that federation science can't duplicate.

The EMH or Moriarty the original sentient hologram are just brute force consequences of computer power and programming with a mundane holographic interface.

So basically the self awareness that should have made Data special was diminished by in universe technology even in TNG.  I'd say the legal and philosophical implications of this were completely ignored. And the answer to your question is that folks who work on AI are really working on nanotechnology that produces AI.

Comment: Do you have a canon reference for how nanotechnology was involved in Data's creation or operation?

Comment: Exploring the legal and philosophical implications of Data's sentience is the entire plot of S2E9 of TNG, [The Measure of a Man](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_(episode)).  Admittedly, after that it is largely dropped again.

Comment: @Ty Hayes "Measure of a Man" does not deal with the fact that holograms can be self aware and that this process appears to be trivial.  The ONLY thing special about Data in a world with Moriarty and the EMH is that the machinery that produces his self-awareness can fit in a human sized head.  There is every reason to believe that in the TNG universe if there was a computer the size of a building hooked up to an android body by wifi or with a hologram interface it could have the same self awareness as Data.

Comment: @lucasbachmann That's completely fair.  I didn't initially get that that was the point you were making  in your answer. Thanks for clearing it up

Comment: I initially DV'd this because it appeared to be arguing elegance is a requirement for sentience, but I thought better. But the question isn't about sentience, it's about why Data is unique, and the answer points out Starfleet's contradictory treatment of their own holograms vs Data. This is explored in The Doctor's own arc.

Comment: Data, yes.  The doctor, yes.  Moriarty, yes.  The key is a strong enough computer to draw on and extended, if not continuous, operation.  Moriarty was created to be able to defeat Data, so he would have been sentient from the start.  The Doctor acquired sentience over time.  The jury is still out on Vic Fontaine.  He has a big enough computer to support sentience.  Indeed, we saw in the episode "Our Man Bashir" that DS9's computer has the space to store multiple human intelligences.  Vic is already "self-aware" so that's a big head start right there.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference is potential capability.

Holographic AIs are hardware limited. You don't want them to interact with something, you don't put any emitters around and isolate them from networks. You could make a power-mad AI and leave them in a box with a speaker, and they could rant away all they wanted and perhaps try and annoy you to death, but that's about it as long as you aren't an idiot and allow them voice access to another computer. As demonstrated in various episodes, you can alter their psychology, delete specific memories, fool around with skill sets by allowing them access or not to subroutines and information, basically treat them like computer programs. One starts getting big for its britches, turn off the computer and reboot them and they're back to their pleasant personality before they went insane.

The Soong-type androids however, are something different. By design, they've got *at least* the same physical capabilities as humans or others, usually more in terms of physical and mental abilities. They're not as easy contain, and, as shown in various episodes, it's not that easy to simply mentally alter them; despite Lore being a threat, Soong wasn't able to make him moral or erase the memory of what he'd done. One of the major issues in the episode [*Clues*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clues_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) was that Data couldn't simply have the memory of the last 24 hours erased like everyone else, and that powering down and rebooting him didn't reset him.

So given an AI that is physically limited in its capabilities and can be easily controlled and prevented from becoming dangerous (despite the fact they *keep making that stupid mistake*, see M-5, Control, Moriarty, etc), versus one that by design is not limited in the same way, there's an obvious reason why people would be blasé about holographic AIs versus the androids. If the AI butler in the holodeck plans to kill you, it's trivial to deal with. If your android butler wants to kill you, you're screwed.